# Combine 2 xml tags with SED

Tags: command-line, sed, xml

I create an xmltv.xml for TV listings and need to use SED for some post processing.  Im using Windows 10 with SED for Windows run via a bat file.
 The trouble is only certain tags are shown on my front end so i need to combine sub-title with desc in the xml.
 I have a current SED command i run to append the sub-title to the title, but can't figure out sub-title to desc.

This is what a channel in the xml looks like, but not all programmes have a sub-title.

```
  <programme start="20160422223500 -0500" stop="20160422233700 -0500" channel="Channel_ID">
<title lang="en">Program Name</title>
<sub-title lang="en">Subtitle Example</sub-title>
<desc lang="en">Description Example</desc>
```

This is how i would append a hockey team from the sub-title to the title using sed.txt

cmd

sed.exe -f sed.txt < "xmltv.xml" > "xmltv2.xml"

sed.txt

```
:a;N;$!ba;s/\(<programme[^<]*\)\(<t[^>]*>\)\(NHL Hockey*[^<]*\)\(<[^<]*\)\(<sub-title[^>]*>\)\([^<]*\)[^<\/programme]*/\1\2\3: \6\4\5\6/g
```

Can someone please provide a command like above to append the sub-title to desc like this?

```
<desc lang="en">Subtitle Example : Description Example</desc>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -nr '/sub-title/ {N;s,/desc,&,;Tprint;s,<sub-title[^>]+>(.*)</sub-title>\n(<desc[^>]+>)(.*</desc>),\2\1 : \3,;:print};p' <<<'<programme start="500 -05" stop="700 -5" channel="Channel_ID">
<title lang="en">Program Name</title>
<sub-title lang="en">Subtitle Example</sub-title>
<desc lang="en">Description Example</desc>

<programme start="600 -05" stop="800 -5" channel="Channel_ID">
<title lang="en">Program Name foo</title>
<desc lang="en">Description Example bar</desc>
> '
<programme start="500 -05" stop="700 -5" channel="Channel_ID">
<title lang="en">Program Name</title>
<desc lang="en">Subtitle Example : Description Example</desc>

<programme start="600 -05" stop="800 -5" channel="Channel_ID">
<title lang="en">Program Name foo</title>
<desc lang="en">Description Example bar</desc>
```

It's a GNU/Linux sed solution but I think it is easy to adapt to Windows.
You can try to use another separator in substitution and the -r option for advanced Regexp to avoid `\/ \( \)`.
I wrote some literal tags (`</sub-title>` `</desc>`) so if there are some extra blanks you would have to adapt.